# Import asp.net solution publish settings (upgraded computer)

Tags: asp.net

I recently upgraded my computer which I use for a lot of asp.net projects among other things.

I moved all my projects over from the old pc to the new one, but I no longer have the publish settings in the solutions (well I assume they are all the same as the current one I am working on).

I did find some import/export available in studio (express) but nothing pertaining to publish, which I assumed to be a solution (or even project) level setting.

It would be most helpful to get my original publish settings, any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Marts

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution quite by accident.

Since I needed to publish something, I started creating a "first" publication profile, and at the and of that process, my original publications appeared in the list.

There must be an issue where the special message "Create Publish Setting" in the profiles list somehow overrides the existing list for new installs of VS.

Martin

Comment: Actually, on another project, I found that the minimum you need to do, is to start the new profile process, then hit cancel and the originals appear.